# Could not find a declaration file for module '../constants/links' | src/constants/links.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my VueJS app I've imported some constant variables.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK, TWITTER_LINK } from '../constants/links'

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private title!: string

  links = {
    moon: MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK,
    twitter: TWITTER_LINK
  }
}
</script>
```

The markup:

```
<p>
  Our first product is <a v-bind:href="links.moon" target="_blank">Moon.holdings</a>, a gamified cryptocurrency portfolio. We are currently working on a roadmap to introduce user accounts and gamified elements to help grow your crypto wealth.
</p>
<div>
  <a v-bind:href="links.twitter" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter"/></a>
</div>
```

And they both work fine in my app, and do click to those links:

[image]

However I'm getting this strange error:

> ERROR in /Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/futuratum.io/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
>   18:50 Could not find a declaration file for module '../constants/links'. '/Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/futuratum.io/src/constants/links.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

My syntax looks 100% fine to me, but what am I missing here in VueJS?

[image]

Comment: you need to write a type definition file for links.js , maybe vue is using --noImplicityAny or --strict when pulling in your imports, which you might be able to turn off

Comment: Oh yeah needed to convert it from js to ts, then do `export const MOON_HOLDINGS_LINK: string = 'https://moon.holdings'` want to post your answer?

Comment: Ha, converting it to ts is one way of getting a type declaration, but honestly you don't even have to do that. when you compile your .ts file take a look at the js and .d.ts file to get a feel for what is needed.   If you import a 3rd party js library that no one has written definitions for you wouldn't want to convert their whole library to ts, just write one of these definition files (which still could be a bit of work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a type definition file for links.js, maybe vue is using --noImplicityAny or --strict when pulling in your imports, which you might be able to turn off.